# Are there a way to use while loop function as a list tracker? and mix with FileI/O?

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, input, while-loop, file-io

```
to_do_list = []
while True:
    in_listed = input('item list:')
    
    if in_listed == 'quit':
        break
        
    if in_listed[0] == 'add':
        num1 = int(user_li[-1])
        to_do_list.append(num1 - 1)
        to_do_list.append(num1 - 1)  
    
        print(to_do_list)

    elif in_listed[0] == 'rm':
        num1 = int(user_li[1])
        to_do_list.pop(num1 + 1)
        to_do_list.pop(num1 + 1)
    
        print(to_do_list)
    
    elif in_listed[0] == 'ls':
        for i in range(len(to_do_list)-1):
            print(f'{i} {to_do_list[i]}, {to_do_list[i+1]}')
```

It works, but I wanted to add an item using `add` and then put an item with the date. For example, when I input `add 5/5 buy milk`, then the output would be `['5/5', 'buy milk']`.

Comment: What you are implementing is called a ["Read-eval-print loop"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop).

Comment: in_listed['0'] is the first character of the input string, not the first word.  So, for 'add 5/5 buy milk' this will return only 'a'.  So the 'add' condition will never evaluate True.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Fixing your `in_listed[0] == 'add'` test

If you want to divide the input string into a list of words, you can use [`strip` and `split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip):

```py
in_listed = input('item list: ').strip().split()
```

Then you can safely test for equality between `in_listed[0]` and `"add"`, `"rm"`, `"quit"`.

### Read-eval-print loop

What you are implementing is called a "shell" or a ["Read-eval-print loop"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop). I suggest simplifying the core of the loop so it reads input, identify a command, and call the appropriate command; the individual code for each command can be separated and put into functions, rather than under an immense `if/elif/else` forest inside the loop.

Here is what the loop might look like after simplification:

```py
env = { 'todo_list': [], 'prompt': '$ ',  'didntQuit': True }

command_dict = {'add': cmd_add, 'rm': cmd_rm, 'print': cmd_print_todolist, 'quit': cmd_quit}

while env['didntQuit']:
    argv = input(env['prompt']).strip().split()           # read
    command = command_dict.get(argv[0], cmd_notfound)     # identify command
    ret = command(argv)                                   # execute command
    print_return_value(ret, argv)                         # error message if command failed
```

We have a dictionary `command_dict` which contains the names of all the commands. In the body of the while loop, we read input; split it into a list of words; look for the first word of the input in the command dictionary; then we evaluate the command found in the dictionary (or `cmd_notfound` if we didn't find a command with that name).

Then we can define the functions `cmd_add`, `cmd_rm`, `cmd_print_todolist` and `cmd_quit` outside the while loop.

Note that I moved all the global variables to a single dictionary named `env` (for "environment") because I am wary of global variable and I prefer to have them all in one place.

### Full code

Here is the full code:

```py
env = {
 'todo_list': [],
 'prompt': '$ ',
 'replname': 'repl-todolist',
 'didntQuit': True
 }

def cmd_add(argv):
    if len(argv) > 2:
        date = argv[1]
        item = ' '.join(argv[2:])
    elif len(argv) == 2:
        date = ''
        item = argv[1]
    else:
        return -1
    env['todo_list'].append((date, item))
    return 0

def cmd_rm(argv):
    if len(argv) < 2:
        print('rm: please specify the index of the item you want to remove')
        return -1
    try:
        i = int(argv[1])
        env['todo_list'].pop(i)
        return 0
    except ValueError:
        print('rm: failed to interpret "{}" as a list index'.format(argv[1]))
        return -1
    except IndexError:
        print('rm: index out of range')
        return -1

def cmd_print_todolist(argv):
    print('TODO:')
    for i, (date, item) in enumerate(env['todo_list']):
        print('  ({}) {} {}'.format(i, date, item))
    return 0

def cmd_quit(argv):
    env['didntQuit'] = False
    return 0

def cmd_notfound(argv):
    print('{}: {}: command not found'.format(env['replname'], argv[0]))
    return -1

def print_return_value(ret, argv):
    if ret != 0:
        print('{}: command {} failed with return value {}'.format(env['replname'], argv[0], ret))

command_dict = {'add': cmd_add, 'rm': cmd_rm, 'print': cmd_print_todolist, 'quit': cmd_quit}

while env['didntQuit']:
    argv = input(env['prompt']).strip().split()           # read
    ret = command_dict.get(argv[0], cmd_notfound)(argv)   # eval
    print_return_value(ret, argv)                         # error message
```

### File I/O

With the code structured this way, it is trivial to add new commands. Just write a new function, and add it to the dictionary of commands!

I suggest you read the tutorial on file I/O in python: [Official Doc on Reading and Writing Files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

Here is an example of a `"save"` command which would write the todo-list to a file:

```py
def cmd_save(argv):
    if len(argv) < 2:
        print('save: please specify a filename to save the todo-list to')
        return -1
    filename = argv[1]
    try:
        with open(filename, 'w') as outf:
            outf.write('TODO:\n')
            for i, (date, item) in enumerate(env['todo_list']):
                outf.write('  ({}) {} {}\n'.format(i, date, item))
        return 0
    except:
        print('save: unable to open file "{}"'.format(argv[1]))
        return -1
```

Then you can add this function to the command dictionary:

```py
command_dict = {'save': cmd_save, 'add': cmd_add, 'rm': cmd_rm, 'print': cmd_print_todolist, 'quit': cmd_quit}
```

### Dates and sorting the todo-list

There is [a python module called `datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) which is really cool if you need to parse, manipulate or print dates and times.
I suggest modifying the function `cmd_add` by replacing the line `date = argv[1]` with something a bit more complex:

```py
def cmd_add(argv):
    if len(argv) > 2:
        date = datetime.datetime.strptime(argv[1],"%m/%d").replace(datetime.datetime.today().year)
        item = ' '.join(argv[2:])
    elif len(argv) == 2:
        date = datetime.datetime.today()
        item = argv[1]
    else:
        return -1
    env['todo_list'].append((date, item))
    env['todo_list'].sort(key=lambda item: item[0])
    return 0
```

Here are the new features:

- Now `date` is no longer a string, but instead a `datetime` object;
- Since the user doesn't specify a year, I added today's year to the date (see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18369590/3080723));
- If the user doesn't specify a date, we add the item with today's date;
- I added `.sort()` at the end of the function. Now your todo-list is sorted by date!

Since the date is a datetime object, we want to modify `cmd_print_todolist` as well to print the time under a good format:

```py
def cmd_print_todolist(argv):
    print('TODO:')
    for i, (date, item) in enumerate(env['todo_list']):
        print('  ({}) {} {}'.format(i, date.strftime('%m/%d'), item))
    return 0
```

I used `'%m/%d'` to format the date, but you could be more fancy and add the day of the week, or write the month in words, etc. See the doc on [strptime and strftime behaviour](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) for more info on date parsing and date printing.

Comment: Thank you so much I appreciate the work that you did and the time that you spend Is it alright for me to claim/use and changes the code to my liking? Sorry for telling this late.

Comment: @Sizzy Yes of course it is alright.